# Livewire - updated hook without render of complex data

Tags: laravel, datatable, hook, laravel-livewire

I'm using Livewire for data table with a complex database query with pagination. In table are also checkboxes and after check/uncheck is quite annoying to wait for render method with fetching all necessary data witch are required only for first component load.

I know I can use `defer` flag for checkboxes but I need also do some action when is any checkbox checked/unchecked so I cannot use that flag. So my question is if I can use updated hook method for checkbox without loading data in render.

Here is my example code:

```
class LivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public $arrayOfCheckboxes = [];

    public function render(SomeService $service)
    {
        $data = $service->fetchComplexData->paginate();
        return view('livewire.some-component', ['data' => $data]);
    }

    public function updatedArrayOfCheckboxes($value)
    {
        // if value is true/false then do some action
        // do I really need to call render and fetch complex data again?
    }
}
```

```
// livewire.some-component.blade.php
<div>
    <table>
        @foreach($data as $row)
            <input type="checkbox" wire:model="arrayOfCheckboxes" value="{{ $row->someValue }}">
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of actions are you doing when you check any of the checkboxes, that shouldn't trigger a render of the component? Sounds like you could attempt to implement some kind of cache, and load from it when there is no data, or when you otherwise need to.

Comment: @Qirel I'm doing bulk actions so I need check them at first and only then call action with render method. But meantime I also need check any checkbox. And unfortunately I cannot use caching - data are very sensitive and I need keep them "live". But yes, otherwise it would be solution.